# Why Can't I View My Application from Heroku Link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

Thank you in advance to all.

Within Heroku's settings you are presented with a given URL for viewing your application when pushed to Heroku; previously it worked and presented me with in fact my application until I pushed to Heroku after my last push and it no longer shows.  Instead it advises to read Heroku logs, and is what I have read.

I'm not quite sure what the issue is exactly, but below I have provided the logs, from Heroku.

```
d-140-142-155-116:the_network CoreyMKimball$ heroku logs
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322064+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322064+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322400+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1530639516747992500_70318106240000'
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322400+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322400+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1):
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322064+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Post", post_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.329790+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=0612b419-e3b9-4b2a-a79b-1dd6ff307e69 fwd="128.208.14.65" dyno=web.1 connect=23ms service=215ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Post", post_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:             <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
2014-03-05T01:01:23.322664+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
2014-03-05T01:01:23.323306+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:27:in `current_user'
2014-03-05T01:01:23.323306+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
2014-03-05T01:01:23.323306+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__3965429488486245911_70318106360440'
2014-03-05T01:01:23.323306+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1530639516747992500_70318106240000'
2014-03-05T01:01:23.323306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:01:23.323306+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:01:22.251681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-03-05T01:05:41.752820+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 128.208.14.65 at 2014-03-05 01:05:41 +0000
2014-03-05T01:05:41.752820+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 128.208.14.65 at 2014-03-05 01:05:41 +0000
2014-03-05T01:05:41.755679+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TheDirectoryController#home as HTML
2014-03-05T01:05:41.755679+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TheDirectoryController#home as HTML
2014-03-05T01:05:41.756778+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered the_directory/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2014-03-05T01:05:41.756778+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered the_directory/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
2014-03-05T01:05:41.765551+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-05T01:05:41.765551+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
2014-03-05T01:05:41.782182+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
2014-03-05T01:05:41.782013+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (16.3ms)
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-03-05T01:05:41.782182+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms
2014-03-05T01:05:41.782013+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (16.3ms)
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Post", post_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.781247+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1):
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__3965429488486245911_70318106360440'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:27:in `current_user'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:             <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.791825+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_toke...
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:                                ^
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:         <ul class="nav pull-right">
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792361+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1530639516747992500_70318106240000'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:             <li><%= link_to "Post", post_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:             <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793018+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:27:in `current_user'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:           <% if signed_in? %>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:           <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:      7:           <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1):
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793018+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `signed_in?'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.792536+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:             <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793018+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1530639516747992500_70318106240000'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793018+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793018+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__3965429488486245911_70318106360440'
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793018+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-05T01:05:41.793176+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=39c5807b-0c3b-49f0-82c0-101f78f12705 fwd="128.208.14.65" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=48ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-03-05T02:07:27.617405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-03-05T02:07:27.618217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-03-05T02:07:31.658462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404776+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404776+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-03-05 02:07:32] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404548+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404776+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-03-05 02:07:32] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404776+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-03-05 02:07:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404776+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-03-05T02:07:32.404776+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-03-05T02:07:34.751816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Updated After 'heroku run rake db:migrate'

```
2014-03-06T03:15:59.086426+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/signin host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=408f3e52-9d9c-4170-a93d-0389495d832a fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=40ms status=200 bytes=2969
2014-03-06T03:15:59.061783+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
2014-03-06T03:15:59.071761+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.069759+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.071761+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.078981+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.079126+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.079691+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 27.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.079576+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 27.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.169427+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signin" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:15:59 +0000
2014-03-06T03:15:59.171239+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-03-06T03:15:59.171239+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-03-06T03:15:59.174766+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.169427+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signin" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:15:59 +0000
2014-03-06T03:15:59.174766+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.175564+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.175564+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.179043+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.179043+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.179364+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.179707+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.179364+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.179707+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.311391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-52795300927c9ea175d1f27797cb7efd.js host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=b42feb4e-b010-4fc3-a549-37bde8ce47fd fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-03-06T03:15:59.312852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-0098dfdc498a3edde1f05b1165e61faa.css host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=5a3ba0d9-8933-4556-a8cf-64d036af39af fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-03-06T03:15:55.411938+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-0098dfdc498a3edde1f05b1165e61faa.css host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=ce7e293f-3ea7-45fd-b004-cb0189831f91 fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-03-06T03:16:14.443250+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:16:14 +0000
2014-03-06T03:16:14.449222+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:16:14.449222+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:16:14.443250+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:16:14 +0000
2014-03-06T03:16:14.449222+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:16:14.449440+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:16:14.461356+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.461356+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.466580+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.466580+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.593366+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (126.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.593870+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.593366+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (126.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.593870+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.594238+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 145ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 124.9ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:14.594238+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 145ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 124.9ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.551704+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:16:27 +0000
2014-03-06T03:16:27.551704+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:16:27 +0000
2014-03-06T03:16:27.580718+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:16:27.580718+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:16:27.580718+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:16:27.580718+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:16:27.615827+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (14.5ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.600183+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.5ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.601120+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.600183+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.5ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.601120+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.615827+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (14.5ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.616263+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.616567+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 18.2ms | ActiveRecord: 11.5ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.616263+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:27.616567+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 18.2ms | ActiveRecord: 11.5ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:36.928299+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:16:36 +0000
2014-03-06T03:16:36.929685+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:16:36.928299+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:16:36 +0000
2014-03-06T03:16:36.929685+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:16:36.929685+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:16:36.929685+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:16:37.180731+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (35.8ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.180731+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (35.8ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.192934+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.192778+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.215508+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.208621+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.216738+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 287ms (Views: 76.3ms | ActiveRecord: 208.7ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.207600+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.196554+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.3ms)
2014-03-06T03:16:37.392767+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/sessions host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=3ee55fa0-29ef-4093-a96b-b3555ae78feb fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=335ms service=674ms status=200 bytes=3145
2014-03-06T03:16:37.224266+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 287ms (Views: 76.3ms | ActiveRecord: 208.7ms)
2014-03-06T03:15:59.176246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/signin host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=46d7213a-8001-485e-bc13-ed724b51ed85 fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=844
2014-03-06T03:15:55.476986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-52795300927c9ea175d1f27797cb7efd.js host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=7f030a94-1483-4960-8621-98c527d22716 fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-03-06T03:16:14.594225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/sessions host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=ceffc5b3-91c2-499e-8208-11def108ac7e fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=173ms status=200 bytes=3186
2014-03-06T03:18:52.419777+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:18:52 +0000
2014-03-06T03:18:52.425448+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:18:52.425325+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:18:52.420806+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/sessions" for 128.208.185.186 at 2014-03-06 03:18:52 +0000
2014-03-06T03:18:52.424363+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-03-06T03:18:52.458526+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.458526+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.425448+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5vKM/h0mGdXi39wQnFhg/aW+HRyHeFwQxcMUQ7H3e9c=", "session"=>{"email"=>"coreymkimball.social@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
2014-03-06T03:18:52.455322+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.455563+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.512420+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 30.0ms | ActiveRecord: 55.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.512118+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.511683+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (52.7ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.512118+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.512420+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 87ms (Views: 30.0ms | ActiveRecord: 55.1ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.511683+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (52.7ms)
2014-03-06T03:18:52.535474+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/sessions host=tranquil-beach-4610.herokuapp.com request_id=ccb92951-c51f-41ae-af81-cbe8b14ce023 fwd="128.208.185.186" dyno=web.1 connect=144ms service=150ms status=200 bytes=3145
2014-03-06T03:21:26.369913+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by coreymkimball@gmail.com
2014-03-06T03:21:30.136478+00:00 heroku[run.9894]: Awaiting client
2014-03-06T03:21:30.174236+00:00 heroku[run.9894]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-03-06T03:21:30.273838+00:00 heroku[run.9894]: State changed from starting to up
2014-03-06T03:21:34.178263+00:00 heroku[run.9894]: State changed from up to complete
2014-03-06T03:21:34.163393+00:00 heroku[run.9894]: Process exited with status 0
```

SessionsController#User

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
```

Comment: `PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist` << did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I can't exactly decipher the response from the log with Heroku, however, my site has been deployed to Heroku's custom URL, so the migrate was assumably helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: I am now being presented with the inability to log in with app on Heroku and deployed; it simply will not log in with user and appropriate details. I have updated log with new log after running your suggested command.

Comment: Post the code for `SessionsController#create`. It looks like you're doing a POST, the rendering the `sessions/new.html.erb` over and over. Does the user you're trying to log in with exist in the Heroku db?

Comment: How do I check for validity in the Heroku database?

Comment: Validity of what? If you're trying to see if a user exists, you can run `heroku run rails console`, and do something like `User.find_by(email: 'email@example.com')`

Comment: I've edited my initial post with requested SessionsController#Create, with interest in troubleshooting why exactly I cannot log in with user after app is deployed.

Comment: After running User.find_by(email: '') with targeted user's email account, it's coming up nil; so another question would certainly be at this point how does one go about updating the Heroku database with the current, and existing database on my Mac.

Comment: Heroku has a guide for that, check [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: I've read over the guide and I cannot seem to get the script to generate a dump file, do I have to install anything specific?  It's giving me a bash, stating that the command is not found.

Comment: This is a separate question. You've got to do some research - there are plenty of questions on SO regarding PostgreSQL data import/export. Look into those _first_ and then ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Great, thanks- been doing some research.

Comment: I've been doing some pecking around here this afternoon and I can't seem to figure out the solution to my issue that I am experiencing on my end; I have deployed my app to a custom URL, but it won't accept a login from a user on my database.  So, after following instructions on the Heroku website regarding i/e of the db- I can't seem to get the pg_dump command to work, as it returns a bash and command not found.  What gives?  I would like to work this problem out here before creating secondary thread.  Thanks in advance to you all.